# Shortest Ruby Quine

Tags: ruby, quine

Just finished reading this blog post: http://www.skorks.com/2010/03/an-interview-question-that-prints-out-its-own-source-code-in-ruby/

In it, the author argues the case for using a quine as an interview question.  I'm not sure I agree but thats not what this question is about.

He goes on to construct a quine in Ruby and refactor it to make it shorter.  He then challenges the reader to try to make it even shorter.

I played around with it for a while and came up with the following:

```
s="s=;puts s[0,2]+34.chr+s+34.chr+s[2,36]";puts s[0,2]+34.chr+s+34.chr+s[2,36]
```

This is the first time I have ever attempted a quine and I can't figure out how to make it any shorter.

What is the shortest Ruby quine you can come up with?  Please post an explanation if your implementation requires it.

Comment: If you are wondering, a quine is a program which, when run, prints it's own source code.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: Here is my shortest Quine:

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "shortest, non-trivial quine"?

Comment: Also, the shortest (non-zero length Quine): 
eval s=%q(puts"eval s=%q(#{s})")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately RubyGarden doesn't exist anymore. Here are a couple of links to make up for it (the one Kevin posted is not the shortest one anymore by the way):

[The first quines in Ruby](http://rubyhacker.com/ruby-quine.html)

```
s="s=%c%s%c; printf s,34,s,34,10%c"; printf s,34,s,34,10
```

[ruby quine *slightly* smaller than python quine](http://blog.zenspider.com/2006/09/ruby-quine--slightly--smaller.html)

```
_="_=%p;puts _%%_";puts _%_
```

[shortest nozero [sic!] ruby quine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190906161925/http://www.justskins.com/forums/shortest-nozero-ruby-quine-122609.html)

```
puts <<2*2,2
puts <<2*2,2
2
```

Comment: Thanks, thats just what I was looking for.

Can you explain the syntax on the last one?

Comment: It's actually explained on the second page of the thread linked above. Quote: "puts <<2" - print all the text from after this statement until you
reach the string "2".

...."*2" - Print that string twice
....",2" - And then print the value 2

The second "puts <<2*2,2" is just text, and the final "2" is the
delimiter.

Comment: It works on Perl too! http://pastebin.com/0YVrr4wN

Comment: Here's the link Michael Kohl refers to, with the eplanation of the third quine: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/dhG250t0FxY (see the last 23/10/03 post).

Comment: Nice. All those quines are missing a newline, though.

Comment: `_="_=%p;puts _%%_";puts _%_` is great but to understand how it works you'd better replace `_` with normal variable name, say `a` and play with it in `irb`

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
$><<IO.read($0)
```

15 characters, not including the newline

Comment: Not a quine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)#.22Cheating.22_quines

Comment: A quine isn't allowed to read from itself.