# Output Ruby class

Tags: ruby, class

This, will be a very strange question. And I really doubt it is possible. Some will call this stupid, and I wouldn't agree more. But it is for mere curiosity!

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    print "Ha"
  end
end
```

Is there a way to print the class file? I mean, create a .txt file, containing exactly the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use the magic constant `__FILE__` which contains the path to the file that you use it in:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    puts File.read(__FILE__)
  end
end
```

This will print the contents of the file containing the definition of `MyClass` every time you create a `MyClass` object.

Comment: I see! Thanks. Is there any other way, thought?

Comment: @Omega: Sure, you could also do `File.open(__FILE__) do |f| f.read end` or ``cat #{__FILE__}` instead of `File.read(__FILE__)`. But there's no way without using `__FILE__` and some way of reading a file from the file system.

Comment: @sepp2k: It is indeed possible to print a ruby program from a ruby program without using `__FILE__` and without reading from file system.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474861/shortest-ruby-quine for some examples.

Comment: @Don: If that's what the OP meant, I completely misunderstood the question (thinking about it I probably did). I thought he wanted to print the source code of the class as a means of reflection. A quine of course requires you to already know the contents of the file.

Comment: @sepp2k: Since he accepted your answer, I doubt you misunderstood too badly!